# on Change of dropdown list showld call the php function

Tags: php, jquery

On change of the dropdown list, A php function should called.

Inside the PHP function I will do some calculation. Later I need to set the value of a text box or else that PHP function should return a value that value shoul be catch in the javascript and set that valu to the textbox control.

My html function is

```
<select name="sltLeaveType" id="sltLeaveType" class="formSelect" onchange="TotalCountsOfPL(this.value)">
        <?php
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
</select>
```

And in PHP function is placed in D:/Project/EmployeeDetails/EmpLeave.php

```
class clsGetTotalPL 
{
    function GetTotalPL($EmployeeId)
    {       
        $query = "select count(leave_request_id) from hs_hr_leave_requests where leave_type_id='LTY002' AND employee_id=".$EmployeeId.";";
    return $query;
}
```

So now please [prvide me the JQuery function to call this Php function 
to get call the GetTotalPL() function on every change on the the dropdownlist.

Comment: without code we can't help u. and also mention desired output

Comment: Please could u provide me the code for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call a php function from js or html, but you can do that by ajax call to a php function where you can perform your calculation and then return the result value to js, so then you can do by js to html...

**Update:**

```
<select name="employee" id="employee" onchange="getIPL(this.value);">
   <option value="">Select Employee</option>
</select>    

function getIPL(id)
    {
            $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       url: "EmpLeave.php",
                       data: "emp_Id =" + id,
                       success: function(result){
                         $("#somewhere").html(result);
                       }
                     });
    };


 // Empleave.php file....
  if(isset($_GET['emp_Id'])){
     GetTotalPL($_GET['emp_Id']);
 }

 function GetTotalPL($id){
  // do your calculation...
}
```

Comment: Thanku @ime.. Actually I need to return a value or variable from GetTotalPL($_GET['emp_Id']); to getIPL(id) function. and set that value to a text box.

Comment: Now its clear, you can set your ajax function and pass information to Empleave.php, and return data as echo or return from GetTotalPL function...

Comment: If I write echo"document.getElementById("txtTotalLeave").innerHTML=calculatedValue;" in side the function getIPL() wil it work.

Comment: Only return that value like => echo $calculatedValue;, and then in success function where result variable is use for representing those return value.. and assign it to a id (#somewhere) in html element.... if you find this help full please vote and select answer.. thanks..

Comment: Ya sure I will vote you sir. But if u don't mind Could You prived the exact code. I need to assing the returned value to the text control called txtTotalLeave. i.e $("#txtTotalLeave").html(result); is it right.

Comment: You Have provide every thing But at the end you r not responding. Please respond me soon.

Comment: hmm, yes.. thats right, but first you need to start the coding, and test each line by echo ""; exit; or alert() in js to ensure that you are on the right way... then assigning to a text control is not difficult....

Comment: My function is inside the Class called clsGetPL() so how can I call it. in ajax. please answer for this. I wont disturb u again.

Comment: yar, only go to that php file, and then. call that function by calling   through its object simple....

Comment: See this the php file.     require_once ROOT_PATH . '/lib//LeaveType.php';  
if(!isset($_GET['emp_Id'])){
   GetTotalPL($_GET['emp_Id']);
class Leave {  // class body
  }  Is it right way?

Comment: mean not use ! in isset(), because you want to check if this is set then execute...  r u got the point.

Comment: @ime, Then        require_once ROOT_PATH . '/lib//LeaveType.php';   GetTotalPL($_GET['emp_Id']);         class Leave {  GetTotalPL(param)(//function body) // class body  }. Is it right?

Comment: i say firs start from select to call a ajax function and where you need to test the function for working or not, (alert("working");) and then go step by step .... clear..

Comment: @Indu.. whats happened... to your script...?

Comment: I am still confused, about calling a function from a class... will it be like `onchange="clsGetTotalPL->GetTotalPL(this.value);"`   ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert your function in a php file to excute , then you could call php file with ajax ( i suggest u use jQuery  )

```
///////////////////////// foo.php

<?php

Function foo (){

// Your process

}

foo();

?>

///////////////////// text.html

<select name="test" id="test" >
<option>.....</option>
.
.
.
.
</select>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').change(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "foo.php",
        success:function(){
        // Your function after execute foo.php

        }
            })

})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @user703617. And how can I get the calculated(which has calculated in foo()) value in JQuery($.ajax).

Comment: In the end of your function write json_encode(Data //string or array) -> function foo(){ ..... echo json_encode($data)    } then you could get $data by    type: "GET",
        url: "foo.php",
        success:function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON ( data); // your array will be here data[0],data[1],.... if you used it as array i recommend you use array

        }