# Refreshing webpage via JavaScript that is triggered by HTML select with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a strange problem where I cannot get a php webpage to refresh that is triggered by a pulldown. Here is the main file (SelectForceRefresh.php):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" /><!-- Optimistically rendering in Chrome Frame in IE. -->
                <title>My form</title>

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
        </head>

        <body>
            <script>
                function ConfigFileSelection(id)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "RefreshConfig.php",
                        data: "confFile = " + id,
                        success: function GotHere()
                        {
                            alert("Got here!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>

            <select name="userconfigoption" onchange="ConfigFileSelection(this.value);" >
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </body>

    </html>
```

And here is the 'link' file (RefreshConfig.php):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['confFile'])){
    CopyUserConfig($_GET['confFile']);
}

function CopyUserConfig($id)
{   
    header("Location: SelectForceRefresh.php");
    exit;
}

?>
```

The problem is that the javascript function is fired when I make a selection from the pulldown because I see the alert "Got here!", but the other php file is never triggered for the refresh. I have been on this for three days not knowing what I'm missing. I have reviewed the other solutions here on Stack Overflow like this one:

[on Change of dropdown list showld call the php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108495/on-change-of-dropdown-list-showld-call-the-php-function)

Where I tried to learn this technique from, but they simply do not work.

What am I missing here? Both files are in the same directory. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not let the PHP file that you target with your AJAX function refresh your webpage.
The best way is do if in the success function of AJAX (so with JavaScript).
Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "RefreshConfig.php",
    data: "confFile = " + id,
    success: function GotHere() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, putvande. But is there any way that I can get the php file itself to reload server side rather than the javascript client side?

Comment: Yes you can, but not via AJAX. The PHP that does the refresh should be on the same page. So you can post your form to the same page (without AJAX) and refresh it.